# When creating an RSS Feed using Rome, how can I add Comments?

Tags: java, rss, rome

I want to create a RSS Feed using Rome (it looks like the site is abandoned).

For each entry, I would like to add a Comments element. Comments is part of the RSS spec:

**comments** : URL of a page for comments relating to the item.

How I can add comments to the SyndEntry?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a custom module. See the Rome Tutorial [here](https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4227201#RssandatOMutilitiEs%28ROME%29v0.5Tutorial,DefiningaCustomModule%28bean,parserandgenerator%29-SampleModuleBean)